# How do I manage syslog data from a firewall

Tags: parsing, firewall, syslog

I want to capture firewall Syslog data for the analysis purpose. What are the best practices for the same? In 10 min 300MB+ data is generated, so not sure dumping it in DB would be a feasible approach.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools available for this. I'd recommend LogZilla, since I work there, but a few other popular solutions are Splunk, ELK, and Loglogic. You would need to set up a server to receive the events, then configure your device to send its logs to that server. This would allow you to search those messages, as well as configure alerts for service impacting events. Managing your logs is an important part of network administration and has many benefits, so do your homework to determine your needs before selecting a solution.

Answer (score 0):

After much research with various free and paid solution, we have finalized on https://www.graylog.org. Setup on the digital ocean was very straightforward. Primary because of strong API support besides other good stuff. It has log rotation settings that help to keep the log size under control.

Hope this helps.